# How to make an asp.net login form (that uses an existing sql database) from scratch?

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, forms, authentication

I'm new to asp.net. I've experience using php, and there it was quite simple to make a login form that compares the login data to those in a predefined database. The thing is, now I need to use a MSSQL database in which among other things the login data are stored. I tried using php with mssql but that turned out quite complicated. Could anyone please give me some tutorial on how to make this work in asp.net, or suggest another solution?

Comment: It would probably help if you can explain why using PHP with MSSQL was "complicated" for you (e.g. a specific framework, library or function doesn't work with MSSQL) and what you consider "simple" to be. At an abstract level it doesn't matter what language or database you use, so focusing on your specific problems would be useful.

Comment: ASP.NET includes a built in Membership provider that includes a simple API for almost all aspects of user management. A key advantage of this is that it takes care of properly salting and hashing passwords to help protect the plain text password in the event your database is compromised (this is still a major disaster, salting and hashing is only a last line of defense). User management by definition is not "simple" to set up from scratch, you should use tools unless you have a good reason not to. With reference to your question, are you using PHP with MSSQL, or ASP.NET and which language?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [tutorial](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/how-to-create-simple-login-form-using.html). I hope that would give you an idea.